# Adding another option to the Source drop down box

Tags: webform-civicrm

Using webform civicrm, how can one add another source option to the wizard?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  You are more likely to get a helpful answer if you could provide some more information.  Could you please edit your question to add more details.  In particular the version of CiviCRM and the CMS you are using (e.g. WordPress, Drupal or Joomla).  A screenshot of the screen you are referring to would be helpful too.

Comment: You may find the answer to your question in the [user guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/)

Comment: What source option? What wizard? Please explain. A screenshot would help.

Comment: I think my answer is what they need. Julia??

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged as webform civicrm - I am guessing you mean the Source Label that you can find if you go to the CiviCRM tab on the webform and then go to Additional Options